# Raster of Latitudes and Longitudes

Tags: r, raster

Given `raster` object `r`, how can I create a new raster with the same extent and resolution, with cell values equal to the latitude (or longitude) of the corresponding cell in `r`?

For example, `r` might look like:

```
r <- raster(matrix(runif(100), ncol=10))
```

Comment: You could first create/read in your raster, then extract each cell's lat or long with `xFromCell()` or `yFromCell()` respectively, then assign the extracted values as the new cell values with `setValues()`

Comment: Don't forget to tag the language - without your other post we'd have no idea what environment you're attempting this in. (I've tagged it as [tag:R])

Comment: I took the liberty of clarifying your question and adding an example raster... I hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is about create a new raster object which has the same extent and resolution of another raster object you can use command `template`

`template` is Raster* or Extent object used to set the extent (and CRS in case of a Raster* object). If not NULL, arguments xmn, xmx, ymn, ymx and crs (unless template is an Extent object) are ignored

```
r <- raster(matrix(runif(100), ncol=10))
r1 <- raster(x, template=r)
```

Answer (score 14):

You can use the `init` function

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(nrow=10, ncol=10)
lon <- init(r, 'x')
lat <- init(r, 'y')
```

Or with terra

```
library(terra)
x <- rast(nrow=10, ncol=10)
lon <- init(x, 'x')
lat <- init(x, 'y')
```

Comment: Neat - didn't know about this.

Answer (score 6):

A simple way to do this is to (1) duplicate raster `r`, (2) extract its coordinates with `coordinates`, and (3) assign the longitudes or latitudes to the new raster objects' cells.

For example, using your `r`:

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(matrix(runif(100), ncol=10))
lat <- lon <- r
xy <- coordinates(r)
lon[] <- xy[, 1]
lat[] <- xy[, 2]
```

And here's what they look like:

```
plot(setNames(stack(r, lon, lat), c('r', 'lon', 'lat')))
```

[image]

Comment: Cool! Now if I wanted this map for the entire globe, where could I set the extent ?

Comment: @IDelToro: Try `r <- raster(extent(-180, 180, -90, 90), res=1)` (set res to your preferred cell size, which is expressed in degrees in this case)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone's just looking for a global raster of latitudes to download, and less interested in how it was made, I've posted one here:

Positive and negative values (90S is -90):
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fV1pnvlzi2PTJM7e6zx0S5IMP1mg09m-

Just positive values (90S is 90):
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ibyNAp1c0E_DY9bFF-1gJw0vizKRmDUT

These were posted at .1 degree intervals.

Python code to generate:

```
import rasterio
import numpy as np

cellsize = .1
xedges = np.arange(-180,180,cellsize)
yedges = np.arange(90,-90,-cellsize)
XI, YI = np.meshgrid(xi,yi)

t = rasterio.transform.from_origin(xedges[0], yedges[0], cellsize, cellsize)

with rasterio.open('latitude.tif', 'w', driver='GTiff', 
                         height=YI.shape[0], width=YI.shape[1],
                         count=1, dtype=np.float32, transform=t) as src:
src.write(YI.astype(np.float32), 1)

with rasterio.open('latitude_abs.tif', 'w', driver='GTiff', 
                         height=YI.shape[0], width=YI.shape[1],
                         count=1, dtype=np.float32, transform=t) as src:
src.write(np.abs(YI).astype(np.float32), 1)
```